# AssertionError: Thrift API version mismatch. (Client: 12, Server: 13)

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I am installing Twissandra - a python example on top of Cassandra.  [Instructions Here](http://github.com/ericflo/twissandra/blob/master/README.md). After successfully compiling and building all dependencies on Lubuntu 10.04 (with Thrift 4.0 and then tried with 2.0)--when I run the last step with the webserver--it crashes and posts this Apache Thrift error:

`AssertionError: Thrift API version mismatch. (Client: 12, Server: 13)`

Is this a thrift problem (4.0) and or a Cassandra problem (7.0 beta)?  Cassandra reports in its logs

`INFO 23:52:01,487 Cassandra version: 0.7.0-beta1-SNAPSHOT 
  INFO 23:52:01,487 Thrift API version: 13.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too just a few days ago. If you update both thrift and pycassa it will work, they're both at 15 now I believe.

Comment: pycassa is now on version 16 - but I think you are on the right track so I moved my accepted answer here

Answer (score 1):

twissandra has not yet been updated for Cassandra 0.7.  Use 0.6.5